# How to deduce the measurablity of $y-f(x)$ from the measurablity of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY420.png)

From the context of Stein's (see the image above), in corollary 3.8 he directly said the function $F(x,y)=y-f(x)$ is measurable from the previous proposition, but I think it is not obvious enough because I can only make sure for a fixed $y$ that $F(x,y)$ is measuble. I can't get it why it's measurble when the two variables $x$ and $y$ combined together since either $y$ is not countable nor considering another function $G(x,y)=F(x,y)-y$ still help me nothing. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) A couple of notes: Please use MathJax for the math in the future. Importantly, please don't include crucial parts of the question in a picture, since these are not searchable, among other reasons. In this case, you should have written the statement of Cor 3.7 in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb R^{d+1}\to \mathbb R$, $g(x,y) = y$ and $h:\mathbb R^{d+1}\to \mathbb R$, $h(x,y) = f(x)$. Then $g$ and $h$ are measurable by  Cor 3.7, so
$$
F(x,y) = g(x,y) - h(x,y)
$$
is measurable.